# Are emojis web safe?

Tags: emoji, web-safe-fonts

I want this character . It shows up perfectly in IE9+, FF, Chrome and Edge.

According to http://caniemoji.com/ support is pretty good for modern browsers on any platform.

Can I just use the emoji instead of linking to an image?

Answer (score 0):

As you state, support was pretty good two years ago and it's even better today.
You can use the emoji instead of an image pretty safely.

One thing to consider though: It will look different depending on the Emoji-font the OS is using.

**Example**
[image: Light Bulb Emojii on different operating systems]
Source: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f4a1